# Does Sitecore XM Cloud support custom code e.g. scheduled tasks, computed index fields

Tags: xm-cloud

What support does Sitecore XM Cloud have for custom code within the CM role (such as computed index fields, scheduled tasks etc)?

Comment: Those are really 2 separate questions. Can you post 2nd one as a separate question?

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great article created by Martin, where he shared something about the customization and the way we can deploy it to XM Cloud. According to the article, it is possible to customize `XM Cloud` in a similar way as we did it with XP by applying patches, but there is an expectation is that developers would customize less and less with time and platform growth. From the functionality point of view, these customizations would focus on data and synchronization rather than patching system features.

You can read the full article here.

https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/ultimate-guide-to-XM-Cloud

You can apply config patches for configuring CM instance, the same as you did before with XP. And here the guide to do that

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/deploy-customizations-to-the-xm-cloud-environment.html

Answer (score 1):

At the moment following features and modules are not in XM Cloud as per the Sitecore documentation (https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/limitations-and-restrictions.html):

1. XP/xConnect/xDB functionality including existing personalization rules (a new embedded personalization experience is available for XM Cloud)
2. Marketing applications, including Experience Analytics, Experience Profile, FXM, Experience Optimization, List Manager, Campaign Creator, Path Analyzer, Marketing Automation, and the Marketing Control Panel
3. Email Experience Manager (EXM)
4. SXA with MVC, and SXA Search components
5. Sitecore Forms
6. Custom search indexes
7. Identity server
8. Sitecore Publishing Service
9. Universal Tracker
10. Device detection
11. IP Geolocation
12. MVC
13. The Update Center